# nginx not accessible outside of Docker container

Tags: nginx, docker

This has to be a simple problem. I'm using boot2docker. If I ssh into boot2docker:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
89ec1492d7c7        mycontainer:latest   "/bin/sh -c nginx"   35 seconds ago      Up 35 seconds       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->1000/tcp   desperate_mestorf
```

Then curl:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ curl localhost:1000 curl: (7) Failed connect to
localhost:1000; Connection refused 
docker@boot2docker:~$ curl
localhost:80 curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Curl'd on port 80 just to make sure I'm not going crazy. Then I connect to my containers bash:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker exec -i -t 89ec1492d7c7 bash
root@89ec1492d7c7:/srv/www# curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css"></head><body><h1>Welcome to Harp.</h1><h3>This is yours to own. Enjoy.</h3></body></html>root
```

Boom! It works, even tried this while leaving the default port 80. What's really weird is I have other containers on my box that I can get to. Even outside of my boot2docker VM (which I'm only using to take one more thing out of the equation). This must be simple right?

Comment: Did you publish the port to the host when starting your container?

Comment: In the dockerfile I have "expose 80" ... I've both exposed the port and not exposed the port, same thing. If I publish this docker file to AWS it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just another the same question in [Unable to connect to Docker Nginx build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202626/unable-to-connect-to-docker-nginx-build)

Here is the way to connect nginx docker container service:

```
docker ps            # confirm nginx is running, which you have done.
docker port desperate_mestorf  # get the ports, for example: 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->1000/tcp
boot2docker ip       # get the IP address, for example: 192.168.59.103
```

So now, you should be fine to connect to:

```
http://192.168.59.103:1000
```

Comment: I had to bind to a different port then set up port forwarding in the VM, don't have to do this for other things so that's kinda weird.

Comment: this resolved my issue although I am using docker-machine thus cmd is "docker-machine ip"