# Unable to connect to Docker Nginx build

Tags: nginx, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

I am trying to host a simple static site using the Docker Nginx Image from Dockerhub: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

A note on my setup, I am using boot2docker on OSX.

I have followed the instructions and even I cannot connect to the running container:

```
MacBook-Pro:LifeIT-war-games-frontend ryan$ docker build -t wargames-front-end .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 813.6 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM nginx
 ---> 42a3cf88f3f0
Step 1 : COPY app /usr/share/nginx/html
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 61402e6eb300
Successfully built 61402e6eb300
MacBook-Pro:LifeIT-war-games-frontend ryan$ docker run --name wargames-front-end -d -p 8080:8080 wargames-front-end
9f7daa48a25bdc09e4398fed5d846dd0eb4ee234bcfe89744268bee3e5706e54
MacBook-Pro:LifeIT-war-games-frontend ryan$ curl localhost:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
MacBook-Pro:LifeIT-war-games-frontend ryan$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                     NAMES
9f7daa48a25b        wargames-front-end:latest   "nginx -g 'daemon of   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 443/tcp   wargames-front-end
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of localhost, use boot2docker ip. First do `boot2docker ip` and use that ip:
`<your-b2d-ip>:8080`. Also you need to make sure you forwarded your port 8080 in VirtualBox for boot2docker.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to connect nginx docker container service:

```
docker ps            # confirm nginx is running, which you have done.
docker port wargames-front-end  # get the ports, for example: 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 443/tcp
boot2docker ip       # get the IP address, for example: 192.168.59.103
```

So now, you should be fine to connect to:

```
http://192.168.59.103:8080
https://192.168.59.103:8080
```

Comment: I got a connection refused: http://pastebin.com/6hiAGeYm
Someone mentioned forwarding ports in virtualbox?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it to work.

```
docker kill wargames-front-end
docker rm wargames-front-end
docker run --name wargames-front-end -d -p 8080:80 wargames-front-end
```

Then I went to my virtualbox and setup these settings:

[image]

Comment: In your example you are forwarding `8080:80` and in the virtual-box you are forwarding `8001`. Just a note :)

Comment: I actually changed it for my example because I decided with a different port. But that wasn't the problem!